# excel VBA - function to parse data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to parse a webpage but am having difficulty in getting the information coming through.

I have a simple button which navigate to a website in a worksheet

```
Private Sub Sellit_Click()
Dim IE As Object
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
IE.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com/"
Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents

Scrape

End Sub
```

While the function Scrape in a module

```
Function Scrape()

Dim IE As Object
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

MsgBox IE.document.Title

End Function
```

I kinda think i know the problem here is the IE doesn't go from the worksheet to the module and vise versa but am not quite sure how to fix it.

your help will be much apperciated

Comment: Where does this approach fail? Does `IE.ReadyState` never equal `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`? Is `Scrape()` called? Within Scrape you never bind `IE`, `HTMLDoc` or `oHTML_Element` to anything.

Comment: sorry i am very new to vba, i called Scrape after the IE.readyState = Readystate_complete, and i wanted the existing IE's document.title and am testing it with the msgbox to see if i get a return, apparently not. How can i have the existing IE's title ?

Comment: I see where you attempted to call `Scrape` but my question was is the macro executing that far or is it getting hung up in the loop. The second part of my previous comment still is true, `IE` is never set to anything within `Scrape`. `IE` in `Scrape` is not the same as `IE` in `Sellit_Click`. The Dim Keyword redimensions it in memory at a different location. You can eithier pass `IE`, rebind `IE`, or use a global varriable for `IE` [Varriable Scope](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) is important here.

Comment: thanks, variable scope is what i need to read up upon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to declare the `IE` object variable publicly, then refer to it using it's fully qualified name. To do so:

1. At the top of the `Worksheet` code module type `Public IE as Object`
2. Remove variable declarations to `IE` within the `SellIt` Click event and the `Scrape` function. Since this is declared publicly, it shouldn't be declared privately within the code.
3. In the standard module, also remove the `IE` declaration. (Same reason as step 2)
4. Change `MsgBox IE.document.Title` to include the sheet's codename. For example, if the sheet codename is `Sheet1` it should read `MsgBox Sheet1.IE.document.Title`

Let me know if that helps.